# Prioritzing AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on building a questionnaire that asks for information about around 400 locations. Each location needs to have between 10 and 40 questions.
In the location overview I want to show whether all required answers have been given, but determining this takes almost half a second per location. This made loading the page take way too long. This has been solved (for now) by retrieving the location status asynchronously with the following code:

```
$(function () { // On document load
        $('.location').each(function () {
            var locationId = $(this).data('location_id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/location/' + locationId + '/complete',
                success: function (result) {
                    var locWait = $('#comp_l' + locationId + 'wait');
                    locWait.hide(); // Hide loading spinner
                    if (result == 'true') {
                        var locYes = $('#comp_l' + locationId + 'yes');
                        locYes.show(); // Show completion mark
                    } else {
                        var locNo = $('#comp_l' + locationId + 'no');
                        locNo.show(); // Show incomplete mark
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The above code makes the site load significantly faster (2 seconds instead of 2 minutes) and the (in)completion marks appear in the following time.

So far this is all working as desired. The problem appears when the user tries to load the location details. The details are loaded using this function:

```
function load(id) {
        var detailPane = $('#detail_pane');
        detailPane.html('<h3><span class="fa fa-pulse fa-spinner"></span>  Loading location details</h3>');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/location/' + id + '/details/',
            success: function (html) {
                detailPane.html(html).show();
                draw(); // Does some final checks on the detailPane
            },
            error: function (error) {
                detailPane.html('<h3>Could not retrieve location details</h3><br><p>' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4) + '</p>');
            }
        });
    }
```

Since there are still calls made to the back end concerning the completion of the locations, the details will only load after all the marks have been drawn correctly. Is there any way I can make sure that the details are loaded in time?

Comment: Instead of sending (potentially) 40 AJAX requests and flooding your server, put all the `locationId` in to an array and send a single request. Your current logic is basically DDOSing yourself

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, why not just have **one** API request and let the server figure out whether a questionnaire has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least <s>two</s> three approaches to this:

1. Instead of sending 40 separate ajax requests to the server, send **one** with the list of 40 locations you want. Most browsers and servers allow at least two connections between the browser and server, so if that call is outstanding, it shouldn't block a single additional ajax call (but your mileage may vary, always test to be sure). The server may serialize calls within a session, so you'll need to allow for that if it does.
2. Alternately, only do one ajax request at a time using a queue (starting the next request when the previous one finishes), and when you need to load information the user's asked for, put it at the front of the queue. Then it will only wait for the currently-running request to complete, rather than all of them.
3. Use socket I/O instead of ajax requests for the 40 locations. But that may be a big hammer.